# How can I make my Warcraft II (DOS) saves work in Warcraft II BNE?

Tags: warcraft-2

I still have my old Warcraft II saves from the DOS version. When I copied them to my BNE saves folder, I was disheartened to find they didn't show up in-game. Yes, I'm aware I can use cheats to jump to the general whereabouts I left off years back, but I'm not sure where exactly that was. Is there any way to upgrade these saves to the BNE format?